# Large regions of the plane $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ with no relatively prime points: $\mathrm{gcd}(x,y) > 1$

Tags: number-theory

For any  $\ell > 0$ can you find $M, N$ such that $ \boxed{\mathrm{gcd}(x,y) > 1}$ for **all** $x \in [M, M+\ell]$ and **all** $y \in [N, N+\ell]$ ?

This is related to the statement that the set of integers $(x,y)$ such that $x, y$ are relatively prime has natural density $\frac{6}{\pi^2} \approx \frac{2}{3}$.  I always read there are arbitrarily large patches in the plane with numbers that are **not** relatively prime.

This is kind of like finding long strings of consecutive composite numbers.  The usual answer is $N! + k$ with $0 \leq k \leq N$.

Comment: About your last assert: it is for $2\le k\le N$, since $N!+1$ can be prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Choose $(\ell+1)^2$ distinct prime numbers $$p_{i,j},\quad 0\leq i\leq\ell,\quad 0\leq j\leq\ell.$$ We might imagine that these are entries of a square matrix and form their row-wise and column-wise products as follows: $$q_i=\prod_{j=0}^\ell p_{i,j}\qquad\text{and}\qquad q^j=\prod_{i=0}^\ell p_{i,j}.$$ By construction the numbers $q_0,\ldots,q_\ell$ are pairwise coprime. The same holds for $q^0,\ldots,q^\ell$. Therefore, by the Chinese remainder theorem, the two systems of congruences $$x\equiv -i\pmod{q_i},\qquad 0\leq i\leq\ell,$$ and $$y\equiv -j\pmod{q^j},\qquad 0\leq j\leq\ell,$$ admit solutions $x$ and $y$. By construction, $x+i$ is divisible by $q_i$ and $y+j$ by $q^j$. Since $q_i$ and $q^j$ are both divisible by $p_{i,j}$ this means that $$\gcd(x+i,y+j)\geq p_{i,j}$$ completing the construction.

Comment: What do you mean **pairwise distinct**?  We have infinitely many prime numbers, so it's good.  I am guessing you mean distinct along each **row** or each **column** ?

Comment: @johnmangual: The point is that e.g. choosing $p_{i,j}=3$ for all $i,j$ doesn't work, because the $q_i$ will not be coprime anymore, violating the assumptions of the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: this is perfect.  the number you get using [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) get pretty large, but all I asked is *some* way to assure me the existence of large holes.