# A property of every set of ten consecutive integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the following example of ten consecutive integers we can see that $119$ and $121$ are each coprime with the others:
$$114=2*3*19$$
$$115=5*23$$ $$116=2^2*29$$ $$117=3^2*13$$ $$118=2*59$$ $$119=7*17$$ $$120=2^3*3*5$$ $$121=11^2$$ $$122=2*61$$ $$123=3*41$$
This example illustrates a general property.

**Prove that in every set of ten consecutive natural integers there is an integer (not necessarily unique) that is coprime with the other nine.**

NOTE.- Someone of respectable reputation made a comment (which has been deleted) in stating that this beautiful result was false for which he quoted a post of StackExchange in which apparently had implied a denial of this property. I say this because I read that post slightly but did not keep the link. I appreciate much if someone makes me know this reference  I wanted to study.

Comment: The link was this, but it does not imply that your result is false; this is why I deleted it.: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410523/large-regions-of-the-plane-x-y-in-mathbbz2-with-no-relatively-prime-poi

Comment: Thanks very much Ajotatxe. I did not known you were who maked that comment. (This was not "my" result: I read the exercise in a blog and I wanted to solve it).

Comment: By the way, the example illustrated the post is the "smallest" set of ten consecutive numbers in which there is not a prime (all the ten are composed).It was "mine" but not the property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given any $10$ consecutive positive integers , does there exist one integer which is relatively prime to the product of the rest ?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140703/given-any-10-consecutive-positive-integers-does-there-exist-one-integer-whic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In such a set, there are exactly $5$ odd numbers. No more than two of them are multiple of three, and exactly one of them is multiple of five. There may be also a multiple of seven among the five odd numbers, but no more than one.

Therefore, at least one of the ten numbers $n$ is not a multiple of $2$, $3$, $5$ or $7$. The least prime factor of $n$ is greater than $10$ and thus, $n$ must be coprime with the other nine numbers of the set.

Comment: An interesting question comes up: is there any finite set $S$ of two or more consecutive positive integer numbers such that none of them is coprime with every other number of $S$?

Comment: @ajotaxe: I like your answer (read my edit, please). Respect of your comment, I feel that the number 10 is "the best". If I have understood well your requirement (maybe not!). Regards.

Comment: @ajotatxe, I've posted an answer to the interesting question in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

This addresses an ancillary question raised by ajotatxe in a comment beneath his answer. (It's too long to post as a comment itself.)  The question was whether there can be *any* string of consecutive numbers for which no entry is coprime to all the others.  I'll show there is such a string.

Consider a string of $20$ numbers $N, N+1, N+2,\ldots,N+19$, where $N$ satisfies the following congruences:

$$\begin{align}
N&\equiv0\mod(2\cdot3\cdot11\cdot13\cdot19)\\
N+7&\equiv0\mod5\\
N+5&\equiv0\mod7\\
N+1&\equiv0\mod17
\end{align}$$

Such an $N$ exists by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Clearly $N,N+2,N+4,\ldots,N+18$ all share a common factor of $2$.  As for the odd entries, $N+1$ shares a factor of $17$ with $N+18$; $N+3$, $N+9$, and $N+15$ share a factor of $3$; $N+5$ shares a factor $7$ with $N+12$; $N+7$ and $N+17$ share a factor of $5$; and $N+k$ for $k=11$, $13$, and $19$ share a factor of $k$ with $N$.

There may well be smaller examples; this construction was simply what came to mind.  It might, in fact, be of interest to find the *first* such string, or the *shortest* such string.  (It's not clear, to me at least, that the first such string is necessarily the shortest.)